# Using an apostrophe; Centres or Centre's?

Tags: apostrophe

My sentence says:

> Coventry city centre's main transport links.

but there is a red line under "centre's" in MS word. Is it "centres" or "centre's"? I thought that you use an apostrophe for belonging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _NEVER_ rely on MS Word for spelling, grammar, or anything else that might be said to have anything to do with any kind of standard. In fact, just never rely on MS Word at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this list is about the English language, not about spelling dictionaries from software applications. In addition this is an elementary question which should have been sent to ELL when it was still fresh.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have MS Word configured to be checking for American English or British English? The British spell the word as "centre" and Americans spell it as "center". If MS Word is checking American English, it will mark "centre" as incorrect.

The correct possessive form of "centre" is "centre's" and the correct possessive form of "center" is " center's".

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was looking at it the American English way.

Comment: @Eduardo The fact that it was a ***red*** underline should have been a clue: red underline signifies a spelling error. Grammar/punctuation errors get green or blue underlines.

Answer (score 0):

It's *centre's*. MS Word often gets it wrong.

Comment: FGITW :P beat me by four seconds...